# Get calling table from column option

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-table

I have a few Bootstrap table on one page. Each table has some data attributes (like `data-link="test-page"` and so on). Besides that, one column of each Bootstrap table uses a [column formatter](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/column-options/#formatter), using `data-formatter="actionFormatter"`. However, I want to get the current table data attributes when actionFormatter is called, so based on the data attributes I can return a string.

Both `this` and `$(this)` return an Object, which doesn't work. `$(this).closest('table').data()` doesn't work either, while I expected that one to be the most true.

Here's the code I use:

```
<th data-field="actions" data-formatter="actionFormatter" data-events="actionEvents">Actions</th>
```

`this` returns a JSON object with the row properties, and `$(this).closest('table').data(XXX)` return undefined. I expected it to return an array with all the data attributes.

Is there any way to get the current processing table from within the formatter?

Example code:

```
<!-- table 1 -->
<table
    data-actions="edit,remove"
    data-url="some/url"
>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-formatter="actionFormatter">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<!-- table 2 -->
<table
    data-actions="edit,remove"
    data-url="some/url"
>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-formatter="actionFormatter">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>


// actionFormatter:
function actionFormatter(value, row, index, field) {
    // get data-actions from the right table somehow, 
    // and return a string based on data-url/other
    // data attributes
}
```

Comment: Could you add minimal code to reproduce the behaviour you are explaining?

Comment: Done! Added an example code to reproduce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that when the action formatter is called, the execution context `this` is an object with all the bootstrap table row associated data as well as all the `data-*` attributes of the row.

Taking that into account you can add an id to each table and a `data-table-id` attribute to your rows like:

```
<table
    id="table-1"
    data-actions="edit,remove"
    data-url="some/url"
>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-formatter="actionFormatter" data-table-id="table-1">Actions</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

so that in your formatter you can retrieve the table DOM Element by using that id:

```
function actionFormatter(value, row, index, field) {
    // get data-actions from the right table somehow, 
    // and return a string based on data-url/other
    // data attributes
    var data = $('#' + this.tableId).data();
}
```